# javascript returns NaN when calling server side function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, server-side, nan, pagemethods

I have the following javascript code that is trying to call a server side function:

```
    function server_GetStats(nodeID) {
        var result = PageMethods.getStats(nodeID);
        return result;
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        newVal = parseInt(server_GetStats(1089)) + parseInt(server_GetStats(1090));
        rate = (newVal - val) / (pollTime / updateCounterTime);
    }, pollTime);
```

And this is the server side function that is being called:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static int getStats(object nodeID)
    {
        int stat= 0;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString();
        conn.ConnectionString = connStr;
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT stat FROM NODE_PROPERTIES WHERE NodeID = " + Int32.Parse(nodeID.ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        stat = Int32.Parse((cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()));
        conn.Close();
        return stat;
    }
```

I've added asp:ScriptManager to the aspx page as well. Can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting NaN. I checked that the SQL statement is OK too. Could someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer:

As was suggested I added a callback function. Ended up looking something like this:

```
    setInterval(function () {
        newVal = 0;
        server_GetStats(1089, 1090);
    }, pollTime);

    function server_GetStats(nodeID) {
        PageMethods.getStats(nodeID, OnGetStatsSuccess, OnGetStatsFailure);
    }

    function OnGetStatsSuccess(result) {
        newVal = parseInt(result);
        rate = (newVal - val) / (pollTime / updateCounterTime);
    }

    function OnGetStatsFailure(result) {
        //do something when your server-side function fails to return the desired value
    }
```

Code-behind stayed the same.

Comment: JavaScript is client side script and cannot directly call server side functions.

Comment: I did some research that indicated that I could use PageMethods to access server side functions?

Comment: No, you need Ajax to access the serverside PageMethods.

Comment: @Virendra - that's the answer to the question, so why put it as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: It isn't the answer, as `PageMethods` is calling the method with ajax.  It's the whole point of `PageMethods`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling a `PageMethod`, it is getting called asynchronously.  That means, when you call `server_GetStats(1089)`, it is returning from that function before the `PageMethod` even completes.  To get your code to work, you'll need to define a callback for your `PageMethod` call.  Something along these lines:

```
var values = 0;

function myCallback(result) {
    values += parseInt(result);

    // Maybe call a function here that notifies/changes the UI.
}

function server_GetStats(nodeID) {
    PageMethods.getStats(nodeID, myCallback);
}
```

Reference: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View30F417D1-8E5B-4C03-99EB-379F167F26B6.htm

Comment: Ahh I see now. I understand :) How do I put up my working solution so that others who stumble upon this might be helped?

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code you used to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following [this tuto](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Call-WebMethod-from-Javascript-in-ASPNET.aspx). Also, first try returning some fixed value from the webmethod (maybe JavaScript is returning NaN because an expiration period due to the query to the database).